# AWS S3 Lifecycle rule not triggered after about 2 weeks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an S3 lifecycle rule like this:

[image]

[image]

But this rule doesn't move any old or newly created objects into "glacier instant retrieval".

I've heard that it takes a few days for a S3 lifecycle rule to trigger. But I've waiting for about 2 weeks.

Why are my files in the bucket still in "Standard" storage class?

[image]

Is there anything else that I should configure?

Comment: Is glacier the right choise if you just gonna store the file for a year. It's some cost for move the files into cold storage. Maybe S3 IA is a better choice... Regarding the rule I don't know but the times I have tested lifecycle rules they have worked the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the S3 Lifecycle [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html), lifecycle on Glacier Instant Retrieval only supports objects larger than 128 KB.

It should be possible to copy the objects manually to that tier if you desire but they will be billed at a minimum of 128KB per object, so for your small object sizes that may be a much larger cost